# Alinear footer dentro de un div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Dado que el nuevo sistema de BS4 hace que las columnas de un row tengan el mismo tamaño, estoy buscando que mi `div.footer` siempre quede al final, al ser elementos estáticos deberían tener un poco de simetría independiente de cuanto mida el div padre

```
 <div class="footer">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-left">Kardex</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Perfil</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center fs15">
        <a class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
        <a class="text-muted ml-2"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Siempre debe estar pegado el final del div padre para que todos se vean iguales, reitero, sin importar el contenido que esté arriba de ellos y el tamaño del contenedor.

```css
.footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="shadow p-3 mt-2 border border-gray bg light col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <h6 class="text-center">Alberto Siurob</h6>
    <p class="fs08 no-margin">Adeudo <span class="text-success  font-weight-bold">$ 0</span></p>
    <p class="fs08 no-margin">Producto(s)</p>
    <ul class="fs07 list-unstyled">
      <li class="text-info ml-2">Lentes solares Ban Ray</li>
      <li class="text-info ml-2">Última generación AYM</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <span class="fs05 float-right">Miembro desde<br><b>12 Abril 17</b></span>
      <span class="fs05 float-left">Modificado por<br><b>Administrador</b></span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-left">Kardex</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Perfil</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center fs15">
        <a class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
        <a class="text-muted ml-2"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow p-3 mt-2 border border-gray bg light col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <h6 class="text-center">Alberto Siurob</h6>
    <p class="fs08 no-margin">Adeudo <span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">$ 1,342</span></p>
    <p class="fs08 no-margin">Producto(s)</p>
    <ul class="fs07 list-unstyled">
      <li class="text-info ml-2">Deluxe AYM</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <span class="fs05 float-right">Miembro desde<br><b>10 Abril 19</b></span>
      <span class="fs05 float-left">Modificado por<br><b>Administrador</b></span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-left">Kardex</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Perfil</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center fs15">
        <a class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
        <a class="text-muted ml-2"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow p-3 mt-2 border border-gray bg light col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <h6 class="text-center">Alberto Siurob</h6>
    <p class="fs08 no-margin">Adeudo <span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">$ 212</span></p>
    <p class="fs08 no-margin">Producto(s)</p>
    <ul class="fs07 list-unstyled">
      <li class="text-info ml-2">Lentes solares Ban Ray</li>
      <li class="text-info ml-2">Última generación AYM</li>
      <li class="text-info ml-2">Deluxe AYM graduados</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <span class="fs05 float-right">Miembro desde<br><b>1 Mayo 18</b></span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-left">Kardex</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Perfil</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center fs15">
        <a class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
        <a class="text-muted ml-2"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow p-3 mt-2 border border-gray bg light col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <h6 class="text-center">Alberto Siurob</h6>
    <p class="fs08 no-margin">Adeudo <span class="text-success  font-weight-bold">$ 0</span></p>
    <p class="fs08 no-margin">Producto(s)</p>
    <ul class="fs07 list-unstyled">
      <li class="text-info ml-2">Lentes solares Ban Ray</li>
      <li class="text-info ml-2">Última generación AYM</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <span class="fs05 float-right">Miembro desde<br><b>12 Abril 17</b></span>
      <span class="fs05 float-left">Modificado por<br><b>Administrador</b></span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-left">Kardex</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Perfil</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center fs15">
        <a class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
        <a class="text-muted ml-2"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui estoy usando unicamente clases que provee Bootstrap 4, evitando usar floats por completo ya que a veces pueden causar comportamientos no deseados;

Basicamente se hace que cada `col-*` sea tambien un flex-container con la clase `d-flex` y cambiamos la direccion del contendor para que se alinie todo en una columna en vez de una fila con `flex-column` esto en escencia *gira* el contenedor y lo coloca de manera vertical; para evitar las clases `float-left` y `float-right`, simplemente utilizo `justify-content-between`, que hace que los elementos del contenedor se alinien a los bordes;

Finalmente especifico que la caja especificamente del contenido (cree un nuevo `div` para esto que encapsula las listas y demas contenido aparte del footer) para que siempre utilice todo el espacio sobrante de modo que se mantenga alineado con la columna mas alta de la fila, usando `flex-grow-1`.

De este modo, el `footer` siempre sera empujado hasta abajo sin necesitar de posicion relativa o absoluta; ya que el contenedor de arriba se encarga de expandirse para ocupar todo el espacio libre

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 shadow p-3 border border-gray bg light d-flex flex-column align-items-between">
      <div class="flex-grow-1">
        <h6 class="text-center">Alberto Siurob</h6>
        <p class="fs08 no-margin">Adeudo <span class="text-success  font-weight-bold">$ 0</span></p>
        <p class="fs08 no-margin">Producto(s)</p>
        <ul class="fs07 list-unstyled">
          <li class="text-info ml-2">Lentes solares Ban Ray</li>
          <li class="text-info ml-2">Última generación AYM</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span class="fs05">Modificado por<br><b>Administrador</b></span>
        <span class="fs05">Miembro desde<br><b>12 Abril 17</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="footer mt-2 border-top pt-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Kardex</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Perfil</button>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center fs15">
          <a class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
          <a class="text-muted ml-2"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 shadow p-3 border border-gray bg light d-flex flex-column align-items-strecth">
      <div class="flex-grow-1">
        <h6 class="text-center">Alberto Siurob</h6>
        <p class="fs08 no-margin">Adeudo <span class="text-success  font-weight-bold">$ 0</span></p>
        <p class="fs08 no-margin">Producto(s)</p>
        <ul class="fs07 list-unstyled">
          <li class="text-info ml-2">Lentes solares Ban Ray</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span class="fs05">Modificado por<br><b>Administrador</b></span>
        <span class="fs05">Miembro desde<br><b>12 Abril 17</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="footer mt-2 border-top pt-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Kardex</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Perfil</button>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center fs15">
          <a class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
          <a class="text-muted ml-2"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 shadow p-3 border border-gray bg light d-flex flex-column align-items-strecth">
      <div class="flex-grow-1">
        <h6 class="text-center">Alberto Siurob</h6>
        <p class="fs08 no-margin">Adeudo <span class="text-success  font-weight-bold">$ 0</span></p>
        <p class="fs08 no-margin">Producto(s)</p>
        <ul class="fs07 list-unstyled">
          <li class="text-info ml-2">Lentes solares Ban Ray</li>
          <li class="text-info ml-2">Última generación AYM</li>
          <li class="text-info ml-2">Última generación AYM</li>
          <li class="text-info ml-2">Última generación AYM</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span class="fs05">Modificado por<br><b>Administrador</b></span>
        <span class="fs05">Miembro desde<br><b>12 Abril 17</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="footer mt-2 border-top pt-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Kardex</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Perfil</button>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center fs15">
          <a class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
          <a class="text-muted ml-2"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias sensei.